# UITextField font show differently

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

i am doing one application.In that iam using `UITextField` and set the font as system font with 16 and minimum font size as 18 . And before editing,the textfiled data is not shown correctly but when i commited to edit then that text shows correctly.Please check the images below.[image]

[image]

so please help me how can show text fully before editing also.

Comment: can you please put some code of your work .. ?